# Obtain reference to network interface from struct sock

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I'm working on tracking network activity per process. Towards this, I've added some fields to `struct sock` to keep track of the PID when the socket is created. This would then allow me to update the `task_struct` when the data is finally sent/received. However, I'm having difficulty in identifying which network interface is being used.

I see that `struct sk_buff` has a field `struct net_device *dev` which references the network interface, but I don't understand how to reference this from `struct sock`.

Is it meaningful to assume that a `struct sock` is *bound* to an interface? If so, is there an easy way to reference the network interface that is being used?

Answer (score 1):

The physical interface is determined dynamically (sort of). The socket (assuming, for simplicity, a TCP session) just represents a connection between local [IP, port] and remote [IP, pot]. So sending data to the remote requires a routing operation to be performed. This is done by looking in the kernel routing table and determining either a direct machine for the next hop (e.g. if RemoteIP is in a local subnet), or by looking for a fallback ("default gateway") as the next hop. Logically, that operation is done on a packet by packet basis, though there is a caching mechanism to prevent it *really* being done packet by packet.

But it's conceivable that the route/interface being used could change while a connection is ongoing. For example, you might have an established connection already using one interface (due to the default gateway setting), and then the administrator could change the default gateway to point to a different IP address, which could cause packets destined to the remote to be directed out a different interface.

Look at `ip_queue_xmit` to see this working. So, yes, there is a binding to the physical interface via the `sock->sk_dst_cache` which provides a `struct dst_entry` containing the `struct net_device`. But it is conceivable that the entry can be invalidated before the next packet is sent.

Comment: This is interesting. My understanding was that TCP is connection-oriented - implying that once the connection is established, the source and destination IPs are fixed and you cannot change it. If the interface was not fixed, then wouldn't the server reject the packet given that its originating from a different source IP? I guess I need to go back and revisit my networking basics :|

Comment: Who said the source IP would change? A route (path through the network) can change without the endpoints changing.

Comment: The norm is that the source IP *will* change if you change the interfaces. The only case where the source IP will *not* change is if they're connected to the same router/NAT.
And in the case where the source IP does change, the connection will be terminated. This is one major advantage of using something like MPTCP. http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/

Comment: Yes, that's the norm. That is why I used the word "conceivable" rather than a different term like "common". It is however not the case that the source IP (i.e. the local side IP) *must* change if the interface is changed. For example, I could provision a new interface on the system for the same network, with a new gateway (or even the same one). It should be able to continue operation of an existing session. Also, there is nothing to prevent an asymmetric routing configuration (outbound on B with inbound still on A [where my initial IP address is on A]).